# Returning a trait type with static dispatch

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to return a statically dispatched trait in a function declared in the same trait, but the compiler seems unable to map between the trait type and the concrete type.

Example:

```
trait Money {
    fn trade<M>(&self) -> M
        where M: Money;
}

impl Money for Dollar {
    fn trade<M>(&self) -> M
        where M: Money
    {
        Dollar { amount: self.amount / 2 }
    }
}
```

You can try out the complete example here: http://is.gd/alQGv0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler's in the right here.  What you've told it is that you're implementing a function `trade` which, for any `M` the caller cares to use (so long as it implements `Money`), you will return an instance of that `M`.  And then you go and try to return a `Dollar`.  What if `M` isn't `Dollar`?

What you probably want here, from context, is the following:

```
trait Money {
    fn trade(&self) -> Self;
}

struct Dollar {
    amount: usize,
}

impl Money for Dollar {
    fn trade(&self) -> Dollar
    {
        Dollar { amount: self.amount / 2 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Dollar { amount: 10 };
    println!("{}", x.trade().amount);
}
```

Here, the `trade` function is changed to always return the type it's implemented for; within the `Money` trait definition, that's `Self`.  When you're talking about a *specific* implementation, it's the implementation type (so it's `Dollar` when you're implementing `Money` for `Dollar`).

Comment: Excellent! I wasn't aware of the Self keyword! Thank you! Well described!